# How to select and deselect the radio button in Typescript AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, typescript

How to select and deselect the radio button in angular?

I have tried  the below sample in Typescript angular but no luck. Is there anyway to implement the same.

Problem was scope false is not updating when the condition is true.

http://jsfiddle.net/cksanjose/67joun8s/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="500"  id="csRdoIntendYes" ng-model="vm.checked" name="optradio1" ng-click="vm.uncheck($event)" >Yes</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="1000" id="csRdoIntendNo"  ng-model="vm.checked" name="optradio2" ng-click="vm.uncheck($event)" >No</label>
</div>
```

**Typescript**

```
uncheck = function (event) {          
    if (this.checked == event.target.value) this.checked = false;           
}
```

Comment: I think you'd review how you're binding the model val and events. Are you using Angular 2, or Angular JS?

Comment: If you are using `AngularJS` then use `AngularJS` not just `Angular`

Comment: nope. I want to select/deselect the radio button of each.

Comment: Toggle class for being selected and deselect.

Comment: Problem is every time my condition is getting true for some reason. Not at all going to else statement. I tried this too...

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is updated, but you can catch scope change only in the end of the digest. Demo http://jsfiddle.net/ttu4kcq8/

If you want to catch current model value in your handler you could schedule it in the end of current digest using `$timeout` service http://jsfiddle.net/ttu4kcq8/1/

Comment: Problem is every time my condition is getting true for some reason.  Not at all going to else statement.  I tried this too...   uncheck = function (event) {          
            this.$timeout(() => {
                if (this.checked == event.target.value) {
                    this.checked = false;
                } else {
                    this.checked = event.target.value;
                }
            }, 1000);      
        }

Comment: @klmuralimohan This is because you are checking within the digest thus you're getting an old value. If you use timeout like `$timeout(() => { ... check and all stuff ... }, 0)` you will get a new value in `scope.checked`

Comment: As I mentioned in previous comment. I have tried your approach but no luck.

Comment: Looks like this is an angular js version issue. This works in angular 1.2 but not in 1.4.

Comment: Pls have a look here which is not working in other versions same code..https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29087/

Comment: @klmuralimohan It is not related to version. You may pay your attention on the timeout. You're checking the result in the end of the digest. And they will always be equal. Look at my second fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ttu4kcq8/1/  And try to describe your task a little bit more detailed. Without angular. Just what behaviour you're trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for the radio button select/deselect behaviour rest will be the same. Here what I exactly looking for http://jsfiddle.net/cksanjose/67joun8s/

Comment: I have no idea what I missed out in my fiddle to achieve your result. can you please update here https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29088/

Comment: @klmuralimohan You are checking scope value at the end of the digest. So you're checking new value with new value and it always true. You need to check and assign scope value *outside* of timeout and use it *inside* it. In my example I'm only using `scope.checked` inside the timeout but checking above it. This is required if you want to make sure your old and new values are equal and assign `false`

Comment: Also you are using very old version of angular in your fiddle. Do you want me to provide an example for this particular version?

Comment: Here is your updated fiddle. In that old version you have to use a temporary variable like this https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29090/